# Where to store db credentials in a productive app?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, password-protection

There is a nestJS backend application, which connects to a mongoDB:

```
const user = process.env.USER
const pwd = process.env.PWD
const uri = 'mongodb://' + user + ':' + pwd + '@mongodb:27017
```

As you can see, the credentials to access the db is stored in an `.env` file. Locally it works perfect. But to have access to this file in the productive app (which is a pod in kubernetes cluster), the file has to go to the git repository.

Is this ok? I thought no credentials should be stored in the repository. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

The credentials don't need to be stored in a .env file.  `process.env` will give you the environment of the process.

See node docs [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env)

You can set the environment for your container in Kubernetes, see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/).

Comment: Yes, but my pods are created in a dynamic CI. And the CI has to get the data from somewhere to implement it in the kubernetes environment. So the data has to come from somewhere as I won't create every app manually.